# CSRF token validation failed : PHP POST - SAP

Tags: php

```
$post = null;
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$headerArr = array();
$headerArr[] = 'Content-Type:application/xml';
$headerArr[] = 'Host:' .$host;
$headerArr[] = 'X-CSRF-Token:Fetch';
$headerArr[] = 'X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest';

$xml_data = file_get_contents ("upload.xml");
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Above code i am using to post my xml data to SAP. But i am getting error "CSRF token validation failed", Can anyone help me in figuring out the same.
How to fetch the CSRF token and use the same.
From were i need to get the correct CSRF token.
I am new to PHP & SAP. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please share the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Make a fetch request.

As a first step, the REST client should obtain the valid CSRF token for the current session. For this it makes a non-modifying request and includes a custom header `X-CSRF-Token: Fetch`. The returned [sessionid – csrf token] pair should be cached and used in subsequent REST requests by the client. Another option is to send Fetch request before every REST request and thus to use the [sessionid – csrf token] pair only once.
Example HTTP Request-Response flow:

**Client Request:**

```
GET /restDemo/services/customers/list HTTP/1.1
X-CSRF-Token: Fetch
Authorization: Basic dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==
Host: localhost:8080
```

**Server Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4BA3D75B73B8C4591F1D915BA9C2B660; Path=/restDemo/; HttpOnly
X-CSRF-Token: 5A44B387B75E54417F6C64FF3D485141
...
```

Use the cached [sessionid – csrf token] pair for subsequent REST requests.

Subsequent modifying REST requests to the same application should include the valid jsessionid cookie and the valid X-CSRF-Token header.
Example HTTP Request -Response flow:

**Client Request:**

```
POST /restDemo/services/customers/removeCustomer HTTP/1.1`
Cookie: JSESSIONID=4BA3D75B73B8C4591F1D915BA9C2B660
X-CSRF-Token: 5A44B387B75E54417F6C64FF3D485141
Authorization: Basic dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==
Host: localhost:8080
```

**Server Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

...